# ruby on rails jquery.js and application.js both fire a request per ajax button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

Firefox is firing off two requests when I click on the following button (and all other ajax forms on the page):

```
<%= form_tag(action_object_path, :remote => true) do -%>
  <div><%= submit_tag "run process" %></div>
<% end -%>
```

I do not want this behavior. I pulled up firebug and can see that there are two requests made:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/object/1/action    jquery.js?body=1 (line 8527)
POST http://localhost:3000/object/1/action    application.js?body=1 (line 8527)
```

How do I fix this to only fire one request when I click my button?

One thing I remember that may help diagnose this problem. I know they are both javascript assets and can vaguely remember modifying something with my assets immediately after I started building my app because `rails server` barked at me and told me to precompile (I at least think it was precompile) my assets. I don't remember what I did and so dont' know how to reverse it.

I also read somewhere that firefox's cache may cause it to fire two requests, so I have tried clearing my cache and that does not work.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have an extra binding to these elements' click event.  Are you sure you didn't require `jquery_ujs` twice?

Comment: I did not change any of the default rails java-script includes. In my application.html.erb layout file there is only one java-script include statement in my html head: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: Is jquery_ujs being required in application.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain the problem a bit more clearly than the comments indicate:

The `jquery-ujs` javascript library adds event bindings to change events for elements that would normally generate standard HTTP requests (and are flagged as `:remote`) into AJAX requests.  In Rails you would typically have the `jquery-rails` gem installed and then have the jquery_ujs.js file render in one of several ways:

- add a `require jquery_ujs` line in your application.js manifest
- add a `javascript_include_tag :jquery_ujs` line to your application layout file
- copy the `jquery_ujs` file to your assets and rely on some line in the application.js manifest to pull it in (e.g. `require_tree .`)

Choosing more than one of these methods will cause the library to be linked twice - and will result in the symptoms described.